# Update dynamically created plot in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I create an R Shiny plot and other widgets dynamically using

```
#ui.R
...
uiOutput("main_panel")
...

#server.R
output$main_panel <- renderUI({ 
                              mainPanel(renderPlot({...}), ..., ...)
                              })
```

This works fine, but is it possible to update a dynamically generated plot without changing other dynamically generated widgets? All examples I have found are with statically generated widgets. (I would also be interested how to make dynamically created widgets clickable, etc.)

Comment: Any chance you could give me some feedback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can dynamically generate any compound ui, as I can create named inputs and outputs dynamically and then they respond to events as usual.

```
#ui.R
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that plots random distributions 
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Example"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of observations
  sidebarPanel(
     checkboxInput("show_dynamic_ui", label="Show dynamic UI", value=TRUE)
  ),

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
     uiOutput("dynamic_ui")
  )
))

#server.R
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    output$dynamic_ui <- renderUI({
        if (input$show_dynamic_ui) #NULL when not checked
            fluidPage(
                fluidRow(column(6, sliderInput("dinput", "Number of observations:",min=1, max=1000, value=500))),
                fluidRow(column(12, plotOutput("dplot")))
            )
    })

    output$dplot<-renderPlot({
                       dist <- rnorm(as.integer(input$dinput))
                       hist(dist)
                   })
})
```

Comment: Still not clear to me what you wanted though. Could you elaborate? What is different about this that makes it the correct answer? A screen shot would help understand it too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to be able to update a plot without user input. Assuming I am right, you could use a `reactiveTimer` to asynchronously update it, like this sample that adds a point to a distribution and then updates the plot every half-second.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(position = "left",
                sidebarPanel("Controls",
                  actionButton("gogobutt","Go"),
                  actionButton("stopbutt","Stop"),
                  actionButton("resetbutt","Reset")),

                mainPanel("Plot",
                          plotOutput("histplot")
                          )
))
server <- function(input,output,session) {
   rv <- reactiveValues(x=rnorm(1),run=F)

   autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(intervalMs=500,session)

   observe({
     autoInvalidate()
     isolate({ if (rv$run) { rv$x <- c(rv$x,rnorm(1)) } })
   })

   observeEvent(input$gogobutt, { isolate({ rv$run=T      }) })
   observeEvent(input$stopbutt, { isolate({ rv$run=F      }) })
   observeEvent(input$resetbutt,{ isolate({ rv$x=rnorm(1) }) })

   output$histplot <- renderPlot({
    htit <- sprintf("Hist of %d rnorms",length(rv$x))
    hist(rv$x,col = "steelblue",main=htit,breaks=12)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: Any feedback for me?

Comment: Very nice example, but this is not what I asked.